# jquery form submit and display results in div witout reload

Tags: jquery, html, submit

Good day,

I found some of the code below on stackoverflow, but for the life of me I can't get this to work.  I've played with the code a little bit, but I'm still learning javascript (slowly) and jquery.

What I'd like to do, is to have a search div with a search input, but instead of reloading the page, I'd like a div below the search to display the results, without a reload.  Type in a search and click 'Search'.  Here is my code, which does nothing, I might add:

My jquery version is 1.5.2 and is loaded with the `include("javascript.php");`

```
<?php
include("search_div.php");
include("javascript.php");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("search").submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(html) {
        $("#results").html(html);
    });
    return false; // prevent normal submit
});

</script>

<div id="content">

    <div id="searchdiv">
        <form type="submit" onsubmit="return false;" name="search" id="search" method="post">
        <table border="0" width="850" id="searchquery" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr><td align="center">Search Query: <input type="text" size="50" id="q" name="q"></td></tr>
        </table>
        <table border="0" width="850" id="searchquerybuttons" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <td align="right" width=840><input type="Submit" value="Search">
        </table>

        </form>
    </div> <!-- end search div -->

    <div id="results">
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
            echo "<br><br>Query is: ".$_POST['q'];
            }
        ?>
    </div>  <!-- End results div -->

</div> <!-- End content div -->

<?php
include ("footer.php");
?>

</div> <!-- End of container div -->
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$('#search')` not `$('search')` ?

Comment: This isn't going to be too helpful so I apologies in advanced but you are going about this in the wrong way. You need to search for 'jquery ajax search' and start over. There should be a good plugin out there. Also you need to look at why you are using tables for your structural layout, maybe change it out of more semantic markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the outputted HTML source?

Did you check the javascript error console to see what the errors were, if any?

What are the contents of `javascript.php`? You can't include a javascript library with PHP. You should use something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Also, this:

```
$("search").submit(function() {
```

should be:

```
$("#search").submit(function() {
```

And you should remove the onsubmit attribute from the `<form>` HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the help...  I copied the code verbatim from another article on stackoverflow and the onsubmit attribute was set that way.  Removing it did the trick.  I did have the # in front of the ("search"), but removed it as I was 'fiddling'.  Thanks for the help. :)